# Invalid handle exception on CloseHandle call?

Tags: c++, windows, shared-memory, handles

In my application I open a handle to shared memory that I read/write to/from. I open the handle like so:

```
//Map the shared memory
     d_to_mbx_mem_arr[idx] = reinterpret_cast<Byte*>(MapViewOfFile(to_mem_h,    // handle to map object
                                                       FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // read/write permission
                                                       0,
                                                       0,
                                                       MAILBOX_SIZE_e));
```

The variable getting set here is an array of Byte* (Byte is an alias for unsigned char), so I do a reinterpret cast so I can just use the handle like a standard Byte pointer.

Later I try to release the handle in the following way:

```
CloseHandle(d_to_mbx_mem_arr[p_tool_id]);
d_to_mbx_mem_arr[p_tool_id] = NULL;
```

Since the value is getting set to NULL after CloseHandle and the code calling this method is only single-threaded I know I'm only calling this once. However when I do call it I get the following warning:

"First-chance exception at 0x7c90e4ff (ntdll.dll) in FMLib_Comm_Layer.exe: 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified."

When I break for the warning I see that the handle it is trying to close has a value of "0x01c90000", which seems reasonable to me for a shared mem pointer. Does anyone see a problem with this implementation, or should I assume I've screwed something else up somewhere else?

Comment: Two questions:  (1) Is that handle value the same value that you get when you first obtain the handle?  (2)  Do you call `UnmapViewOfFile` and does that call succeed?  [The order in which you call `UnmapViewOfFile` and `CloseHandle` does not matter, but you must call both of them to release the file.  Both should succeed, though.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `CloseHandle()` on `to_mem_h`, not on the return value of `MapViewOfFile()` (See an example of using `MapViewOfFile()` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551.aspx) -- that example is calling `UnmapViewOfFile()` on the return value of `MapViewOfFile()` and is calling `CloseHandle()` on the first parameter to `MapViewOfFile()`)

Comment: Okay, 1 question. I actually call CloseHandle on to_mem_h right after I've mapped a view of the file even though I continue to use the share file that I've mapped, is this okay?

Comment: Actually, that is in fact okay.  From the `UnmapViewOfFile` documentation:  "Although an application may close the file handle used to create a file mapping object, the system holds the corresponding file open until the last view of the file is unmapped."

Comment: Adding UnmapViewOfFile instead of CloseHandle seemed to fix it. I would be surprised if it were not okay to close the file handle while still using the file mapping object, because I've been doing it for a while now without observable issues.